# $tr(X'X)$ is independent of any scale invariant function of $X$

Tags: statistics

> If rows of $X$ are i.i.d $N_p(0,1)$ ,how to prove that $tr(X'X)$ is independent of any scale invariant function of $X$ ?

Including having no idea of where to start with, I have one more doubt: What s exactly meant by `scale-invariant` function?

Comment: What is $N_{p}(0,1)$? Standard normal? In fact I am confused about dimensions/objects here.

Comment: @Jan Yes , $N_p(0,I)$ refers to standard multivariate $p-$normal with dispersion matrix $\Sigma$

Comment: And $X$ is $p$ vector so that $X'X$ is a number? If $X$ is $1\times p$, then $X'X$ is variance-covariance matrix, well expectation of its version (without subtracting first moments). What am I missing?

Comment: @Jan $X$ by default is a column vector.

Comment: Scale invariant means rotation by an orthogonal matrix. Now it should be simple.

Comment: @LandonCarter You could as well have posted this line in the below section.. One of the most precise hints I have got.. Thanks..

Comment: @Qwerty Wizened men seldom go for upvotes :)